# display all data with only a single object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to java and react. I get this data from backend.

```
   {
    "id": 1,
    "uName": "Example GmbH",
    "uAdresse": {
        "id": 2,
        "str": "Dieselstr",
        "strNum": "160",
        "plz": 48147,
        "ort": "Münster"
    },
    "eMail": "info@example.de",
    "telNummer": "0000000000",
    "uDescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit...",
    "uAngebot": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "sTitle": "Lorem ipsum",
            "sText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit..."
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "sTitle": "Lorem ipsum",
            "sText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit..."
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "sTitle": "Lorem ipsum",
            "sText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit..."
        }
        {
            ....
        }
    ]
}
```

I can fetch and map over the data and display the result (http://localhost:8080/unternehmen/1). All is fine.

Now i want display data, but only with a single object from "uAngebot". The routing is than e.g. http://localhost:8080/unternehmen/1/uAngebot/3.
Any help is highly appreciated.

edit:

```
//unternehmenTest.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const API = 'http://localhost:8080/';
const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'unternehmen/';

class UnternehmenTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: props.id,
            unternehmen: [],
            isLoading: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        fetch(API + DEFAULT_QUERY + this.state.id)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ unternehmen: data, isLoading: false }));
    }

    render() {
        var unternehmen = this.state.unternehmen;
        console.log(unternehmen) // whole object is in console

        var requiredAngebot = unternehmen['uAngebot'].find(element => element['id'] === 3);
        console.log('requiredAngebot', requiredAngebot);

        return (
            <div>hello</div>
        );

    }
}
export default UnternehmenTest;
```

I get this error:
*TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'unternehmen['uAngebot'].find')*

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried in react router. Its routing problem. 
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/recursive-paths
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config

These example will help you

Comment: Can you upload the code to github or somewhere else? Like @ShubhamVerma said, react-router is the solution, but I'm not sure if you are already using it.

Answer (score 0):

from your usrl : http://localhost:8080/unternehmen/1/uAngebot/3 , you can parse last 2 item : **uAngebot/3**

I made a custom fumction : getdata(input) ,where input = **uAngebot/3**

so if you `console.log(getdata('uAngebot/3'))` you will get that perticular result.

---

check the result: click on **run code snippet** button

```js
var data = {
                "id": 1,
                "uName": "Example GmbH",
                "uAdresse": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "str": "Dieselstr",
                    "strNum": "160",
                    "plz": 48147,
                    "ort": "Münster"
                },
                "eMail": "info@example.de",
                "telNummer": "0000000000",
                "uDescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit...",
                "uAngebot": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "sTitle": "Lorem ipsum",
                        "sText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit..."
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "sTitle": "Lorem ipsum",
                        "sText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit..."
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "sTitle": "Lorem ipsum",
                        "sText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit..."
                    },
                ]
            }

            console.log(getdata('uAngebot/3'))

            function getdata(input) {
                result = {}
                obj_key = input.split("/")[0];
                id = input.split("/")[1];
                data[obj_key].forEach ( v => {
                    if (v.id == id){
                        result =  v
                    }
                })
                return result

            }
```

Comment: Thank you. What I want is a single object from uAngebot and the rest of the data e.g. uName, uAdresse.

Comment: I really do not understand your question. can you send a sample, what object you want ? first I thought 'http://localhost:8080/unternehmen/1/uAngebot/3' means you want data -> uAngebot -> id=3 . that's why I send you the above-mentioned example. so if you send the structure of the obj you want, I will try my best. if you think the answer is helpful, give an upvote. thanks

Comment: Are you using any framework like react  or vanila js ??

Comment: Because you have to parse URL and then pass last 2 params  (like : uAngebot/3) to the function I made .

Comment: yes, I use react. The array uAngebot do not have only 3 objects, it can have 0 or 100.

Comment: localhost:8080/unternehmen/id/ -> i get all data. Each object of uAngebot has a "read more"-button. This button redirect to localhost:8080/unternehmen/id/uAngebot/id. When I have the object uAngebot -> id=3, than I want access to the rest of the data. This is my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the object you have mentioned is named as `unternehmen`, you can find the particular object in `uAngelbot` array like this:

```
let requiredAngelbot = unternehmen['uAngebot'].find(element => element['id'] === 3);
```

If you are looking for routing, this might help -> https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

```js
var unternehmen = {
  "id": 1,
  "uName": "Example GmbH",
  "uAdresse": {
      "id": 2,
      "str": "Dieselstr",
      "strNum": "160",
      "plz": 48147,
      "ort": "Münster"
  },
  "eMail": "info@example.de",
  "telNummer": "0000000000",
  "uDescription": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit...",
  "uAngebot": [
      {
          "id": 3,
          "sTitle": "Lorem ipsum",
          "sText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit..."
      },
      {
          "id": 4,
          "sTitle": "Lorem ipsum",
          "sText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit..."
      },
      {
          "id": 5,
          "sTitle": "Lorem ipsum",
          "sText": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit..."
      }
  ]
};


var requiredAngelbot = unternehmen['uAngebot'].find(element => element['id'] === 3);

console.log(requiredAngelbot);
```

Comment: I get "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'unternehmen['uAngebot'].find')" error.

Comment: OK, thank you. I have edited my post. I need to fetch my data. Can you please tell, what is wrong with my example?